# How to set the properties of a bootstrap progress bar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using PHP and I intend to replace the values (valuenow, valuemin, valuemax) with variables.
However, when I change those values the progress bar won't update.
Apparently, I have to change the width% to actually change the progress of the bar. valuenow, valuemin and valuemax don't do anything.
I want to be able to set at least two values (current, max). Otherwise, it doesn't make sense.

Is this just me? I couldn't find any solution anywhere.

Comment: Your code will work, just change the `width:10%` to any value you want like this : `<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>`

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. I just needed to make some calculations before passing in the actual value to the width attribute. just wondering what the valuenow, min, and max are good for then